# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' +HOST

Tags: python

I am VERY new to programming and I found this program and APPLY IT BUT I FOUND  THESE ERROR (I put error at the end of program), 
    import requests
    import telnetlib
    import time
    import sys

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

USERNAME = 'ubnt'
PASSWORD = 'ubnt1'
HOST = "192.168.1.220"
PORT = 18888
TIMEOUT = 10
FRAME_SPEED = 1

LOGIN_URI = 'http://' + HOST + ':80/login.cgi'
#LOGIN_URI = 'https://' + HOST + ':443/login.cgi'

def usage():
 print ("Usage:+ sys.argv[0] +  <live|replay FILENAME>")
print ("")
print ("Options:")
print ("\tlive              \t=\tProcess live data from device ") + HOST
print ("\treplay FILENAME   \t=\tReplay FILENAME")
print ("\trecord FILENAME   \t=\tMake movie of FILENAME")
exit(128)

if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'live':
ACTION='live'
FILENAME = None
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] == 'replay':
ACTION='replay'

ocessing
FRAME_SPEED = 50
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] == 'record':
ACTION='record'
FILENAME = sys.argv[2] # Stored data processing
FRAME_SPEED = 50
else:
usage()



def parse_get_frame_resp(line):
_,vals_raw = line.split(':')
vals = map(int, vals_raw.split(','))
frame_nr = vals.pop(0)
return(frame_nr, vals)

#TODO: Make me dynamic parse from 'SCAN RANGE' response
scan_range_begin = 2402000000
scan_range_end = 2497000000

if not FILENAME:
print ("Enabling Ubiquiti airView at %s:%s@%s...") %(USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST)
s = requests.session()
s.get(LOGIN_URI, verify=False)
r = s.post(LOGIN_URI,
    {"username": USERNAME, "password": PASSWORD, "uri": "airview.cgi?   start=1"},
    verify=False)
 if 'Invalid credentials.' in r.text:
    print ("# CRIT: Username/password invalid!")
    sys.exit(1)
print ("Waiting for device to enter airView modus...")
# Allow device a few moments to settle
time.sleep(TIMEOUT)

print ("Start scanning...")
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, timeout=TIMEOUT)
#tn.set_debuglevel(99)

# Storage on unique files
outfile = 'output-%s.dat' % int(time.time())
print ("Storing output at '%s'") % outfile
fh = open(outfile, 'a')
def writeline(cmd):
    """ Write line to device"""
    ts = time.time()
    tn.write(cmd)
    print (cmd) 
    fh.write("%s\001%s" % (ts, cmd))
    return ts


def getline():
    """Read line from device"""
    line = tn.read_until("\n")
    print (line)
    fh.write("%s\001%s" % (time.time(), line))
    return line

# Commands needs to have a trailing space if no arguments specified
writeline("CONNECT: \n")
getline()

#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2407000000\n") #  5 MHz
#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2412000000\n") # 10 MHz
#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2417000000\n") # 15 MHz
#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2422000000\n") # 20 Mhz
#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2477000000\n") # (ch 1-11 - US   allocation)
#writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2487000000\n") # (ch 1-13 - UK allocation)
writeline("REQUEST RANGE: 2402000000,2497000000\n") # (ch 1-14)
getline()

writeline("START SCAN: \n")
getline()
print ("Waiting for scan to start...")
time.sleep(2)

def get_frame(frame):
    """ Get frame from device airView """
    # TODO: Receiving frames in order, sometimes yield of empty responses.              Already flush out maybe?
    #writeline("GET FRAME: %s\n" % frame)
    ts = writeline("GET FRAME: \n")
    line = getline()
    return((ts,) + parse_get_frame_resp(line))
else:
# No need for logic since we are processing stored data
sh = open(FILENAME, 'r')
def get_frame(frame):
    """ Perform replay data processing """
    while True:
        line = sh.readline()
        if not line:
            return(None, None, None)
        ts_raw, a = line.split('\001', 1)
        ts = float(ts_raw)
        cmd, ret = a.split(':', 1)
        if cmd == 'FRAME':
            return((ts,) + parse_get_frame_resp(a))


 # Get innitial frame number and bins sizes
_, frame_nr, vals = get_frame(None)
bin_size = len(vals)
bin_sample_khz = float(scan_range_end - scan_range_begin) / 1000 / bin_size
print ("Bin size: %s") % bin_size


# Start making picture
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,11))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('UBNT airView Client')
ax.set_ylabel('100ms units elapsed')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (sampled with bins of %s kHz)' % bin_sample_khz)

# Channel center frequencies
a =    [2402,2412,2417,2422,2427,2432,2437,2442,2447,2452,2457,2462,2467,2472,2484,2497]
channels = (np.array(a,dtype='float32') - 2402) / (bin_sample_khz / 1000)
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks(channels)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# Plot channel description
for i in range(1,15):
width_20mhz = 20000.0 / bin_sample_khz
if i in [1,6,11,14]:
    pac = mpatches.Arc([channels[i], 0], width_20mhz, 300, 
        theta2=180, linestyle='solid', linewidth=2, color='black')
else:
    pac = mpatches.Arc([channels[i], 0], width_20mhz, 300, 
        theta2=180, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, color='black')
ax.add_patch(pac)


ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
plticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int((x * bin_sample_khz / 1000) +  2402), ',')))

plt.grid(linewidth=2,linestyle='solid',color='black')
plt.tight_layout()

bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width, height = bbox.width*fig.dpi, bbox.height*fig.dpi
print (width), (height)

# Initial data and history of amount of pixels of the screen, since it is
# important that all lines are draw on the screen.
bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width, height = bbox.width*fig.dpi, bbox.height*fig.dpi

matrix = np.empty([int(height),bin_size]) * np.nan
pcm = ax.pcolorfast(matrix, vmin=-122, vmax=-30)

if ACTION == 'record':
# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='AnyWi UBNT airViewer'),    bitrate=1800)

#
# Matplotlib Animation
#
def update(data):
global frame_nr, matrix

# Fast forwarding in time
for i in range(FRAME_SPEED):

    frame_nr_next = -1

    # The same frame (duplicated), we are too fast
    while frame_nr_next <= frame_nr:
        ts, frame_nr_next, row = get_frame(frame_nr + 1)

    frame_nr = frame_nr_next

    # We are on the end of the file
    if not ts and not frame_nr and not row:
        return

    #matrix = np.vstack([row, pcm.get_array()[:-1]])
    matrix = np.vstack([row, matrix[:-1]])

pcm.set_array(matrix)
ax.set_title('Frame %s at %s' % (frame_nr,time.asctime(time.localtime(ts))))     
#fig.canvas.draw()


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)

# Dual display and recording data does not seems to work, use a screencast
# program like gtk-recordmydesktop for that matter
if ACTION == 'record':
ani.save('live.mp4' if not FILENAME else FILENAME.rsplit('.',1)[0] + '.mp4',  writer=writer)
else:
plt.show()

#
# Takes some time (10 seconds) for device to return to an active state
#


error output
Usage:+ sys.argv[0] +  <live|replay FILENAME>

Options:
live                =   Process live data from device 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ABDULHUSSEIN\Desktop\py-ubnt-airviewer-master\airviewer.py",                                            line 76, in <module>
usage()
File "C:\Users\ABDULHUSSEIN\Desktop\py-ubnt-airviewer-master\airviewer.py",    line 58, in usage
print ("\tlive              \t=\tProcess live data from device ") + HOST
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Any one pls can help me????

Comment: `print ("\tlive              \t=\tProcess live data from device ") + HOST` what is this ?? i think i should be `print ("\tlive              \t=\tProcess live data from device ",HOST)  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `print ("\tlive \t=\tProcess live data from device ",HOST)` not `print ("\tlive              \t=\tProcess live data from device ") + HOST`